# how can I convert to json doctrine association ArrayCollection

Tags: php, json, doctrine-orm, slim

I have the following association

```
class User
{
....
/**
 * @OneToMany(targetEntity="UserNote", mappedBy="user", fetch="EAGER")
 */
public $userNote;
....
}
class UserNote implements
{
 ....
/**
 * @ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="userNote")
 * @JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id_user")
 */
public $user;
....
}
```

The association above, produce the following objetc as result when I select one user that it had some UserNote:

```
App\Models\Entity\User Object
(
[id] => 4
[name] => Filipe Rodrigues
[email] => filipe@email.com.br
[login] => master
[password] => *********
[date] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2016-05-04 00:00:00.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[lastLogin] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-08-09 11:45:38.000000
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[numLogin] => 161
[fone1] => 1112345678
[fone2] => 
[cep] => 09112000
[adress] => Rua Sila NAlon Gonzzaga
[cpf] => 289.233.498-52
[typeUser] => 3
[facebook] => 
[site] => 
[plan] => 
[idPlan] => 1
[note] => 
[fl_vip] => 
[fl_trial] => 0
[fl_cob] => 0
[recorrenceCode] => 0566AEA4DADA9861147E5F95DD2AF24B
[billingDay] => 13
[status] => 8
[token] => 
[parent] => 
[userNote] => Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection Object
    (
        [snapshot:Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection:private] => Array
            (
                [0] => App\Models\Entity\UserNote Object
                    (
                        [id] => 1
                        [note] => teste
                        [date] => DateTime Object
                            (
                                [date] => 2018-01-02 00:00:00.000000
                                [timezone_type] => 3
                                [timezone] => UTC
                            )

                        [user] => App\Models\Entity\User Object
 *RECURSION*
                    )

            )
......
```

So, when I use json_encode I get the following result:

```
{
"id": 4,
"name": "Filipe Rodrigues",
"email": "filipe@vitrinekar.com.br",
"login": "master",
"password": "ndtidis@23",
"date": {
    "date": "2016-05-04 00:00:00.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "UTC"
},
"lastLogin": {
    "date": "2017-08-09 11:45:38.000000",
    "timezone_type": 3,
    "timezone": "UTC"
},
"numLogin": 161,
"fone1": "1112345678",
"fone2": null,
"cep": "09112000",
"adress": "Rua Sila NAlon Gonzzaga",
"cpf": "289.233.498-52",
"typeUser": 3,
"facebook": null,
"site": null,
"plan": null,
"idPlan": 1,
"note": null,
"fl_vip": null,
"fl_trial": 0,
"fl_cob": 0,
"recorrenceCode": "0566AEA4DADA9861147E5F95DD2AF24B",
"billingDay": 13,
"status": 8,
"token": null,
"parent": null,
"userNote": {}
}
```

The userNote didn't convert, how can I convert the doctrine association using json_encode?

Somebody can help me?

Comment: Have you tried to use the Serializer Component of Symfony? If not take a look ["How to use the serializer"](https://symfony.com/doc/current/serializer.html)

Comment: I will try and post the result here. Thanks @YulioAlemanJimenez

Comment: you could try $value["userNote"] = $value["userNote"]->toArray();

Comment: @katona.abel, yes, it's a way, but when I have an array of User object, I can't to iterate the array User object to convert userNote. I just want to return the result.

Comment: @YulioAlemanJimenez it works with symfony! thanks!!